# C#: Root cause of Max pool size was reached

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

We are getting following error in our `WCF application`.

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

When we received the error at the time total 24 connection were consumed by the application and I think 100 is a default connection pool size.

We always close the `SQL connection` and also we dispose the `SQLDataReader`.

I am not sure why this execution occurred. Is there any other situation when we get this error?

Comment: All disposable objects should be disposed, not only the SqlDataReader, but most importantly the SqlConnection. Use the _using statement_ around these kind of objects to get a proper handling of them

Comment: @Steve - Yeah, we use "using" statement to handle connection and SQL Command etc.

Comment: I think you need to investigate more on your service and see if you have not missed the .Dispose() method or the using statement somewhere on your code. Sometimes, it is just a little tiny loop that can cause the problem.

Comment: We need more information about your scenario: Are you using connection pooling? Which .NET Framework version are you using?

Comment: @RicardoPontual - I think SQL pooling is automatically handled if the connection string is same. We are using .NET Framework 4.

Comment: What I meant was if are you using explicit values in connection string, like `Pooling=true; Min Pool Size=5; Max Pool Size=20`

Comment: @RicardoPontual - No we do not use explicit pool size in connection string.

Comment: Just an note of something we ran into on an mssql database.  We had a massive one-time sproc which caused such contention that normal read users were locked out of the db, due to mssql doing a systemwide lock escalation.

Answer (score 3):

I have some sugestions.

1. Implement correctly all connections inside `using` blocks to close/dispose connections (as you said, this is already done)
2. Check which user/machines are keeping opened connections. Run this query to identify the database id:

`select distinct dbid, DB_NAME(dbid) FROM sys.sysprocesses where dbid > 0`

Then, use this query to inspect all opened connections, replacing the **dbid**:

```
SELECT dbid, DB_NAME(dbid) as DatabaseName, COUNT(dbid) as ConnectionCount, loginame as LoginName
  FROM sys.sysprocesses
 WHERE  dbid = 1
 GROUP BY dbid, loginame
 ORDER BY count(dbid) desc
```

This can give you some hint about who is keeping too much connections opened.

3. Implement pooling in connection string to limit connections.
   Use this in your application connection string:

`Pooling=true; Min Pool Size=1; Max Pool Size=5`

I hope this can help you.